# Add Subject Alternate Name to self signed certificate using wincrypt

Tags: c++, certificate, wincrypt, subject-alternative-name

How to add Subject Alternative Name in the certificate. Using wincrypt I have created and added the certificate to "MY" and "root" path where CN can be machine fully qualified domain name or hostname or IP. As Subject alternate name I want to add the following:DNS name=fully qualified domain name, DNS name=hostname and
DNS name=IP
How to do this?
I do not want to use openssl.

```
    LPCTSTR cnName= fqdn;
    DWORD cbEncoded = 0;
if (!CertStrToName(X509_ASN_ENCODING, cnName, CERT_X500_NAME_STR, NULL, 
    pbdata, &cbData, NULL))
    {
    _tprintf(_T("CertStrToName failed 0x%x\n"), GetLastError());
    return 0;
    }
    if (!(pbdata = (BYTE *)malloc(cbData)))
    {
    _tprintf(_T("malloc Error 0x%x\n"), GetLastError());
    return 0;
    }

    if (!CertStrToName(X509_ASN_ENCODING, cnName, CERT_X500_NAME_STR, NULL, pbdata, &cbData, NULL))

{
    _tprintf(_T("CertStrToName failed 0x%x\n"), GetLastError());
    return 0;
}

CERT_NAME_BLOB IssuerBlob;
IssuerBlob.cbData = cbEncoded;
IssuerBlob.pbData = pbEncoded;

CertCreateSelfSignCertificate(NULL, &IssuerBlob, 0, &KeyProvInfo, &Alg, 0, &EndTime, 0);
OpenandAddCertificateToStore(pCertContext, L"MY");
OpenandAddCertificateToStore(pCertContext, L"Root");
```

> > This creates and adds certificate to the store without SAN in the certificate

I tried passing extension list like below:

```
CertCreateSelfSignCertificate(NULL, &IssuerBlob, 0, &KeyProvInfo, &Alg, 0, &EndTime, &myExtns_list);

CERT_EXTENSION myExtn;
myExtn.fCritical = TRUE;
myExtn.pszObjId = szOID_SUBJECT_ALT_NAME;
myExtn.Value = myBlobdata;

CERT_EXTENSIONS myExtns_list;
myExtns_list.cExtension = 1;
myExtns_list.rgExtension = &myExtn;

char cb[20] = { "DNS Names=abc.com" };
BYTE    *pbData = (BYTE*)cb;
CERT_NAME_BLOB myBlobdata;
myBlobdata.cbData = 20;
myBlobdata.pbData = pbData;
```

> > with this I could get the SAN as byte format in the left pane and the right pane shows my string "DNS Names=abc.com".

But my requirement is to show only the DNS Names in the SAN.

Comment: It would probably help if you showed how you were currently creating the certificate.

Comment: Please check the question again I have edited with code

Comment: please help me on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that your building of the extension data actually happened prior to your call to `CertCreateSelfSignedCertificate` (and, likewise, that your building of `myBlobdata` happened before using it).

The main problem is that you used one SAN entry (sort of) as the entirety of the SAN extension; which meant you lost some encoding wrappers. A secondary problem is that you used `szOID_SUBJECT_ALT_NAME`, which is the incorrect OID for Subject Alternative Name... you actually want `szOID_SUBJECT_ALT_NAME2`.

> I want to add the following:DNS name=fully qualified domain name, DNS name=hostname and DNS name=IP

Adding an IP address as a DNS name is non-standard and is supposed to result in a match failure.  You'd actually want to add the IP address as an IP Address SAN entry.

```
CERT_ALT_NAME_ENTRY entries[3];
entries[0] = { CERT_ALT_NAME_DNS_NAME };
entries[0].pwszDNSName = L"example.org";

// IPv4 Address 10.12.1.130
BYTE ip4Bytes[] = { 10, 12, 1, 130 };
entries[1] = { CERT_ALT_NAME_IP_ADDRESS };
entries[1].IPAddress = { sizeof(ip4Bytes), ip4Bytes };

// ::1, big-endian
BYTE ip6Bytes[16] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
entries[2] = { CERT_ALT_NAME_IP_ADDRESS };
entries[2].IPAddress = { sizeof(ip6Bytes), ip6Bytes };

CERT_NAME_BLOB name = { cbEncoded, buf };
BYTE extBuf[1024] = { 0 };
cbEncoded = sizeof(extBuf);

CERT_ALT_NAME_INFO info = { sizeof(entries) / sizeof(CERT_ALT_NAME_ENTRY), entries };

if (!CryptEncodeObjectEx(
    X509_ASN_ENCODING,
    X509_ALTERNATE_NAME,
    &info,
    0,
    nullptr,
    extBuf,
    &cbEncoded))
{
    // Whatever your error handling story is.
    //
    // Note I didn't do a 0 buffer or CRYPT_ENCODE_ALLOC; I just knew
    // that my buffer would be big enough.
}

CERT_EXTENSION extension = { 0 };
extension.fCritical = 0;
extension.pszObjId = szOID_SUBJECT_ALT_NAME2;
extension.Value = { cbEncoded, extBuf };

CERT_EXTENSIONS extensions = { 1, &extension };

...

PCCERT_CONTEXT cert = CertCreateSelfSignCertificate(
    0,
    &name,
    0,
    &keyProvInfo,
    &sigAlg,
    0,
    &certExpirationDate,
    &extensions);
```

In CertUI that gives me the Subject Alternative Name value I expect:

```
DNS Name=example.org
IP Address=10.12.1.130
IP Address=0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much. Exactly what i wanted